# Responsive sizing and scaling

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a landingpage at the moment and a key feature is that is has to be a responsive one. I have a little bit experience with responsive web design but I'm stuck at the moment.

The max width has to be 1280 pixels. So when its on a desktop it has to be 1280px wide and aligned to the center. So scaling grom 1920x to 1280px is fine. But when it comes lower than 1280px I want to let the site scale the content. But since I've put the 1280px as a static width I don't know how I can make this responsive and let it scale with it lower than 1280px

I hope I've explained it good enough. English grammar is terrible sorry.

This is a piece of the code of how my body and container is

```
body
width: 100%
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#de0b1d, #8a0712) /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#de0b1d, #8a0712) /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#de0b1d, #8a0712) /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#de0b1d, #8a0712) /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
.container
    padding: 0
    position: relative
    width: 1280px
    height: 100%
    background-image: url("../img/head-image.png")
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position-y: 150px
```

I think it's because it a static value but how can I make this a responsive one with a max width of 1280 px?

The background image should also scale with the max width of the screen. So I think I have to use Background-size: cover for that, right?

Thanks in regard!

Comment: by scaling the 'site' you mean everything? text and containers?

Comment: you need [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) instead of `width`

Comment: Yea max-width works! Not scale everyhing just position it a diffrent way ;-) But I want to make the container "fluid" and not static so that he only change width at certain widths. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

use CSS media queries to trigger styles when you reach a certain screen width. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/